# Morphia MongoDB check for null and non existing field

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am new to both Morphia and MongoDB. Is there a way to check using Morphia that a certain field in my database is not `null` and also exists. For example from the following record of a user from a collection of users in database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51398e6e30044a944cc23e2e"), 
  "age" : 21 , 
  "createdDate" : ISODate("2013-03-08T07:08:30.168Z"),
  "name" : "Some name" }
```

How would I use a Morphia query to check if field `"createdDate"` is not null and exists.

**EDIT:**
I am looking for a solution in Morphia. So far I have come up with this:

```
query.and(query.criteria("createdDate").exists(),
query.criteria("createdDate").notEqual(null));
```

From documentation, I learnt Morphia does not store empty or null fields. Hence the justification for `notEqual(null)`.

**EDIT 2:** From the answers I can see the problem needs more explanation. I cannot modify the `createdDate`. To elaborate: the example above is less complex than my actual problem. My real problem has sensitive fields which I cannot modify. Also to complicate things a bit more, I do not have control over the model otherwise I could have used `@PrePersist` as proposed in one of the answers.

Is there a way to check for null and non existing field when I have no control over the model and I am not allowed to modify fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [**documentation**](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki#features), Morphia does not store Null/Empty values (by default) so the query

```
query.and(
    query.criteria("createdDate").exists(),
    query.criteria("createdDate").notEqual(null)
);
```

will not work since it seems you are not able to query on null, but can query for a specific value.

However, since you can only query for a specific value, you can devise a workaround where you can update the `createdDate` field with a date value that is never used in your model. For example, if you initialize a Date object with 0, it will be set to the beginning of the epoch, Jan 1st 1970 00:00:00 UTC. The hours you get is the localized time offset. It will be sufficient if your update only involves modifying the matching element(s) in mongo shell, hence it would look similarly to this:

```
db.users.update(
    {"createdDate": null }, 
    { "$set": {"createdDate": new Date(0)} }
)
```

You can then use the **[Fluent Interface](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#fluent-interface)** to query on that specific value:

```
Query<User> query = mongoDataStore
    .find(User.class)    
    .field("createdDate").exists()
    .field("createdDate").hasThisOne(new Date(0));
```

It would be much simpler when defining your model to include a prePersist method that updates the createdDate field. The method is tagged with the `@PrePersist` annotation so that the date is set on the order prior to it being saved. Equivalent annotations exist for `@PostPersist`, `@PreLoad` and `@PostLoad`.

```
@Entity(value="users", noClassNameStored = true)
public class User {

    // Properties
    private Date createdDate;

    ...
    // Getters and setters
    ..

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.createdDate = (createdDate == null) ? new Date() : createdDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake and for the elaborate explanation of the workaround. There is one catch though, I cannot modify the `createdDate`. To elaborate: the example above is less complex than my actual problem. My real problem has sensitive fields which I cannot modify. Also to complicate things a bit more, I do not have control over the model otherwise I agree with your solution of `@PrePersist`. Is there some other workaround?

Comment: @Segmented I'm afraid I don't know any other workaround outside of the one above, seems like modifying the documents is the way to go but then again it's out of your control. I could only think of another workaround where you can query for documents where `createdDate` exists AND doesn't fall in a specific date range, say between now and the start of epoch i.e. new Date(0). That way you can perhaps catch the null values?

Comment: thank you so much for bearing with me and my complicated problems. As much your solution sounds tempting to me (about `createdDate` to fall within a specific date range), I would love to look for some generic solution. I hope that is okay with you, before I embrace your solution...

Answer (score 0):

When you first create your Morphia instance, before calling [`morphia.mapPackage()`](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/MappingObjects#create-a-morphia-instance) do this:

```
morphia.getMapper().getOptions().setStoreNulls(true);
```

to have Morphia store null values.

Anyway, you should be able to query non-null values with:

```
query.field("createdDate").notEqual(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

In mongo you can use this query:

```
db.MyCollection.find({"myField" : {$ne : null}})
```

This query will return objects that have the field 'myField' and has a value that is not null.