# Is there a way to write negation query ( ex nand , nor , not ) in morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I want to write a negation / negative query where I can filter out those sets, where size is zero, but I am unable to write a morphia query for that.

In mongodb :

```
db.getCollection('xyz').find({'ArrayField.0': {$exists: true}})
```

Above query works.

I want to manipulate this query and form a morphia query which can run on arrays/sets for this

```
query.and(
          query.criteria("ArrayField.0").exists(),
          query.criteria("ArrayField").notequals(null)
)
```

Comment: Also you can find useful this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985557/9890613

Answer (score 0):

You were so close!

```java
query.and(
          query.criteria("ArrayField.0").exists(),
          query.criteria("ArrayField").notEqual(null)
)
```

More generally, there's another approach that works more broadly:

```java
query.and(
          query.criteria("ArrayField.0").exists(),
          query.criteria("ArrayField").not().Equal(null)
)
```

This approach should work for any operation.

I should point out the `$equal` operator from the mongo query language is `equal()` not `equals()`.  `equals()` is the Java defined equality method defined on `Object`.  The name is confusing to be sure and, thanks to autocomplete, I've stumbled on that myself.  But it's far too late to change that method name and honestly I haven't thought of anything better to call it.