# Query mongo db with constraint to apply only if a field exists or else ignore

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I am using morphia mongo with java where i am trying to query a set of data with some constraints. I have a very old set of data and with my new change i have added a new field to the existing collection which will be present only in the new records hence i want to frame a query to apply the condition on that collection record if and only if the collection has that field

I have checked few tickets like

[Morphia MongoDB check for null and non existing field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984422/morphia-mongodb-check-for-null-and-non-existing-field)

which is close to this but not exaclty where it is looking for a null field. My case the field is absent

```
Query<MyData> query = mObject.getDatastore().createQuery(MyData.class);
        query.field("field1").hasAnyOf(values);
        query.field("field2").exists().field("field2").lessThan(value);
```

I am looking something like if field2 exists in the collection then only apply the lessthan constraint or else skip this constraint only apply the field1 constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Query<MyData> query = mObject.getDatastore().createQuery(MyData.class);
        query.field("field1").hasAnyOf(values);
        query.field("field2").exists();
        query.field("field2").type(Type.INTEGER_64_BIT).field("field2").lessThan(value);
```

Assuming 'field2' is of type INTEGER_64_BIT.